# prevent console error for addEventListner when it isn't in the DOM

Tags: javascript

I have a scripts file which I use for click events that trigger axios or Ajax requests but in some views that button doesn't exist and there is an error in console that says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

How can I prevent this? Do I have to wrap it in an if statement or surely there is a more elegant way?

```
document.querySelector(".book-now").addEventListener("click", e => {
// declare variables
// send Ajax request
// etc.
```

Comment: "Do I have to wrap it in an if statement" that's one option

Comment: "surely there is a more elegant way" — The elegance of alternatives is highly subjective.

Comment: @Quentin, is there a better option in your opinion?

Comment: @Quentin, you have a massive amount of reputation points so I suspect you have a very good opinion on what would be best :)

Comment: `let bookNowBtn = document.querySelector(".book-now"); if (bookNowBtn) { bookNowBtn.addEventListener('click', e => { /*...*/ }) }`

Comment: How elegant does this look? XD  `(_=document.querySelector('.book-now'))?_.addEventListener('click', e => {}):_`

Comment: @MikeKaskun, looks interesting. Just not 100% sure of the syntax. Looks sort of like shorthand/ternary.

Comment: Yea, it's for fun. Better don't use it. Just wrap with if statement. As alternative you can use `try...catch`, but I would prefer `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a delegate listener instead:

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('.book-now') {
    // declare variables
    // send Ajax request
    // etc.
  }
})
```

If you don't want that (or have to listen to an event that won't bubble) your only option is to check whether the element exists:

```
let bookNowBtn = document.querySelector(".book-now"); 
if (bookNowBtn) { 
  bookNowBtn.addEventListener('click', e => { /*...*/ }) 
}
```

Comment: thank you. I like the .matches

Answer (score 1):

You can first check if the element exist

```
let elem = document.querySelector(".book-now");
if (elem !== null) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", e => {
    //rest of the code
  })
}
```

Comment: `if (elem !== null)` can be shortened to  `if (elem)`.